# Where is the best place to store firewood outdoors relative to your house?

Tags: fireplace

Is it true I should avoid storing firewood near my home (due to concern about termites)? Or is it perfectly fine to store firewood in a convenient spot just outside the door?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Storing your firewood on an elevated rack should alleviate most insect problems.  The wood should not be in direct contact with the ground or with a structure.  Leave enough of a gap to promote air flow around the stack.

Rotate your firewood from season to season (do not stack new firewood on top of old).

If you live in a termite prone area (the southeast or California), you may want to keep your stack further away from buildings, in case they do get a hold of the wood.

Comment: I know this answer is old, but would it be unwise to store firewood on a metal rack sitting on a wooden deck that's about 15 feet off the ground (the house is brick, if that makes a difference)? Getting out into the backyard itself involves traversing a lot of stairs, so I'd like to keep it on the deck if I can.

Answer (score 2):

Where I live termites are only a minor problem. We are more concerned about bushfires. Regardless, most people in the area store their firewood up against the back fence on housing blocks or in a standalone pile at least 100m (30 yards) from any building on larger sites, such as farms. As timber fences are generally treated with creosote nobody's worried about the termites there.

Comment: how is 100m = 30 yards?